# How to Solve This Integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Mathematica insists that the below integral does not converge, though it has been solved by my peers, so I am inclined to think that it does.

q is an arbitrary variable.

```
94.2092*Integrate[
(0.235773*E^(0. - 0.274348/((1 - u)*u) - 
(23.04 - q*(1 - u) + 1.03836*(1 - u)*u)/(8*u))*Sqrt[(1 - u)*u])/
((1 - u)*u^2) + (1/u^2)*0.057487*(0.000048123 + 4.87057*u + 
2.56214*u^2 - 22.761*u^3 + 29.1002*u^4 - 15.6102*u^5 - 4.21906*u^6 + 
8.0764*u^7 - 2.0191*u^8), {u, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: What is `q`? ${}$

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform edited the question. It's an arbitrary variable.

Comment: If you do a series of numerical integrations (I let q=1) like for {u, 0.1, 0.9}, then {u, 0.01, 0.99} then you can see that it blows up. It's 10^6 for {u, 0.0000000001, 0.9999999999}